# COUNT in documentDB is not working

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

i am trying to get the number of documents in my collection (country id id partition key)

when i execute the plain query with out partition key as follows it is getting error

> SELECT COUNT(c.memberId) FROM c
>   **Error :-** Cross partition query only
>   supports 'VALUE ' for aggregates.

late i added partition key in where condition

> SELECT COUNT(c.memberId) FROM c where c.countryId=209

when i execute the query every time i am getting different results like

> [   {
>       "$1": 39161   } ]
>
> [   {
>       "$1": 400454   } ]
>
> [   {
>       "$1": 300454   } ]
>
> [   {
>       "$1": 200454   } ]

why it is not working properly ? is there any mistake in my query?

Answer (score 3):

> When using the Azure Portal's Query Explorer, note that aggregation queries may return the partially aggregated results over a query page. The SDKs will produce a single cumulative value across all pages.

(from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-sql-query#Aggregates))

If you are running your queries in the portal, check whether `HAS MORE RESULTS` is `true` in the information pane. You'd have to sum up all partial results to get the total count.